# Removing fragments from URLs

Tags: perl

I want to get rid of fragments (like #foobar) from URLs, but based on certain rules. Normally a brutal regex would have solved the problem;

```perl
$url =~ s/#.+//;
```

but I want it to take several things into consideration, most notably these transformations

```
http://www.example.com/#/           => http://www.example.com/
http://www.example.com/#foo/bar#foo => http://www.example.com/#foo/bar
http://www.example.com/#foo?a=1     => http://www.example.com/#foo?a=1
http://www.example.com/#foo/?a=1    => http://www.example.com/#foo/?a=1
```

So the rules should be:

1) If /#/, just replace it with /.

2) If # is *not* followed upstream by a / or ?, remove it.

Any ideas how to deal with this properly? One regex or use of other modules?

Comment: I think you should go back to your *requirement* and tell us what that is. How have these "URLs" become so mangled in the first place? Is this a rescue mission to undo the results of a bug in a differnt program?

Comment: Let me rephrase the whole ting. Sorry. :) As long as the '#' is _not_ followed upstream by '/' or '?' it should be removed. The exception is when it's alone, when it should be replaced altogether, but that can be done with a simple s/\/#\///g, so don't focus on that one now. I also removed one I want to keep.

Comment: Ok. So someone changed my post, so I need to rethink the whole thing.

Comment: I updated with better, more precise, examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex `s{#(?:/|[^?/]*)$}{}` will cover these rules as stated:

1. If `/#/`, just replace it with `/`.
2. If `#` is not followed upstream by a `/` or `?`, remove it.

And the test suite to demonstrate:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Test;

BEGIN { plan tests => 4 }

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ($source, $goal) = split /\s*=>\s*/;

    $source =~ s{#(?:/|[^?/]*)$}{};

    ok($source, $goal);
}

__DATA__
http://www.example.com/#/           => http://www.example.com/
http://www.example.com/#foo/bar#foo => http://www.example.com/#foo/bar
http://www.example.com/#foo?a=1     => http://www.example.com/#foo?a=1
http://www.example.com/#foo/?a=1    => http://www.example.com/#foo/?a=1
```

Output:

```
1..4
# Running under perl version 5.018002 for MSWin32
# Current time local: Fri May 30 15:01:04 2014
# Current time GMT:   Fri May 30 22:01:04 2014
# Using Test.pm version 1.26
ok 1
ok 2
ok 3
ok 4
```